# Replace continuity integer in array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort and replace continuity integer in javascript

```
var arrayvals = [1,2,3,10,4,6,12,9];
arrayvals.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

I want to print like that:
`[1-4,6,9-10,12]`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain `[1-4,6,9-10,12]` how the output should be calculated? what is the relation?

Comment: @rajuGT The OP means first order the array i.e. to [1,2,3,4,6,9,10,12], and then where any of the numbers form an unbroken chain .g. 1,2,3,4, convert it to a range 1-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have sorted the array, just loop through it checking for continuity. For example:

```
var arrayvals = [1,2,3,4,6,9,10,12];
var output = [];

for(var i=0; i<arrayvals.length; i++){
    var min = arrayvals[i];
    var cur = arrayvals[i];
    while(cur + 1 === arrayvals[i + 1]){
        cur = arrayvals[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    if(cur !== min){
        output.push(min + '-' + cur);
    }else{
        output.push(cur);
    }
}

console.log(output.join(','));
```

This assumes at least a couple in the processing array, but you should get the general idea. I have created a fiddle you can play with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3zv8eusa/)